# Capturing trace/debug information from a Silverlight OOB app running on a Mac

Tags: silverlight, macos, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-oob, debugview

I'm having a problem with a trusted Silverlight 4 OOB app when it runs on a Mac.

In order to debug I'd really like to be able to capture the debug/trace information output by the app. (The problem is in in code running in a background thread so outputting debug information to the screen isn't practical and risks creating new issues.)

Ideally I'm looking for the Mac equivalent of [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx), if there is one.
If not, any tips on other approaches to debugging htis will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ended up having the app write to a file rather than having any trace output. A bit disappointing. If you end up doing similar I recommend watching out for the size of the file with regard to the amount of allocated space in IsolatedStorage. If a trusted app write the file somewhere else. That will also make it easier to get at :)

Answer (score -1):

In the past I have created a com visible dll in c# that simply uses the standard win32 outputdebugstring call to output debug info.  This can then be called from within Silverlight using COM automation :-)

Comment: ah sorry well pointed out I have missed the point here I retract :-)

Comment: yeah, that was the whole issue. :(